# AWS Cognito Login Data

Tags: amazon-web-services, parse-platform, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, aws-mobilehub

We're trying to figure out whether to create our own Parse server or migrate to AWS stack. We're looking for AWS alternative to Parse login, where it extracts user info such as email and name.

The closest one I could find is AWS Cognito, but it doesn't seem to store any user info (email/name). It seems that the only way to get them is through the developer authenticated identities, which means I have to deal with user's credentials (encrypt the user's password), handle the fb/google registration, etc.

I'm new to AWS Mobile, but I was hoping that these should be a standard feature that BaaS solution should provide. Am I missing something here? For those who uses AWS Mobile stack, how do you handle this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We are using aws mobile analytics stack (sdk and export events to redshift) in our ios application and we run into the same issue you are describing. The only way we have to handle it is to ask the user to provide these details as part of the registration process.
At least in ios there is no way to get the user email and name from the os or through aws.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Amazon Cognito does not support user registration. We have heard this request from multiple customers and we will consider adding this feature in future releases.

Note: If you do decide to do your own authentication using developer authenticated identities, you can use [Amazon Cognito](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-sync.html) to store your user data such as email and other profile information. It also provides offline access and synchronizes data across devices for authenticated users.

Answer (score 0):

Cognito User Pools does what you want (authentication, username, email all sorts of claim data).

It is integrated with Cognito Identity in a fork off of the github repository aws-mobile-hub-helper ([here](https://github.com/BruceBuckland/aws-mobilehub-helper-ios))

That repo contains an AWSSignInProvider for Cognito User Pools. It is also modified to support identity merging across any provider with an AWSSignInProvider implemented (Google, Cognito Your User Pools, and Facebook in that repository).